# Errors from PerfPowerTelemetry/PerfPowerServices

Tags: error, ventura, power-management, metadata

I see these recurring errors from PerfPowerTelemetry

```
No metadata for metric: InstantAmperage

No metadata for metric: AppleRawCurrentCapacity

No metadata for metric: CycleCount

No metadata for metric: Temperature

No metadata for metric: <private>
```

and many others.

Ventura 13.5 on a macbook pro m1 16"

Comment: There is no question here. What is the problem you are trying to solve?